# My open reading frame (ORF) finding code is not finding the longest ORF in the sequence

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics, python-re, biopython

I am trying to code a function that finds the longest Open reading frame. However, in this one instance it is not locating the longest ORF and I cannot figure out why.

This is the sequence:

> GCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAAAATCGACGC
> GGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCTCCCTCG
> TGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGGAAGCGTGGC
> TGCTCACGCTGTACCTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTGGGCTGTGTG
> CCGTTCAGCCCGACCGCTGCGCCTTATCCGGTAACTATCGTCTTGAGTCCAACCCGGTAA
> AGTAGGACAGGTGCCGGCAGCGCTCTGGGTCATTTTCGGCGAGGACCGCTTTCGCTGGAG
> ATCGGCCTGTCGCTTGCGGTATTCGGAATCTTGCACGCCCTCGCTCAAGCCTTCGTCACT
> CCAAACGTTTCGGCGAGAAGCAGGCCATTATCGCCGGCATGGCGGCCGACGCGCTGGGCT
> GGCGTTCGCGACGCGAGGCTGGATGGCCTTCCCCATTATGATTCTTCTCGCTTCCGGCGG
> CCCGCGTTGCAGGCCATGCTGTCCAGGCAGGTAGATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAA
> CGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCG
> CACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAA
> CAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAA
> GCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGG
> CTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTG
> ACGAACCCCCCGTTCAGCCCGACCGCTGCGCCTTATCCGGTAACTATCGTCTTGAGTCCA
> ACACGACTTAACGGGTTGGCATGGATTGTAGGCGCCGCCCTATACCTTGTCTGCCTCCCC
> GCGGTGCATGGAGCCGGGCCACCTCGACCTGAATGGAAGCCGGCGGCACCTCGCTAACGG
> CCAAGAATTGGAGCCAATCAATTCTTGCGGAGAACTGTGAATGCGCAAACCAACCCTTGG
> CCATCGCGTCCGCCATCTCCAGCAGCCGCACGCGGCGCATCTCGGGCAGCGTTGGGTCCT

My code says the longest ORF is 228 nucleotides in length and located between nucleotides 655 and 882. However the longest ORF is actually 327 nucleotides in length and located between nucleotides 575 and 901.

This is my code. I have made sure it does not stop at stop codons not in the reading frame but no success. Can anyone figure out why it doesn't work? I save the sequence as a fasta file and then open it and save the sequence before calling the function.

```
def find_orfs(sequence):

    # Scan through the sequence to find open reading frames
    longest_orf = ""
    strand = ""
    longest_orf_start = -1
    longest_orf_end = -1
    for i in range(3):
        # Search forward frames
        orfs =re.findall(r'(?s)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', sequence[i:])
        for orf in orfs:
            # Find the longest ORF within the sequence

            if len(orf) > len(longest_orf):
                strand = "+"
                longest_orf = orf
                longest_orf_start = i + sequence.index(orf) +1
                longest_orf_end = i + sequence.index(orf) + len(orf)
        # Search reverse frames
        seq_rev = str(Seq(sequence).reverse_complement())
        orfs = re.findall(r'(?s)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', seq_rev[i:])
        for orf in orfs:

            # Find the longest ORF within the sequence
            if len(orf) > len(longest_orf):
                longest_orf = orf
                strand = "-"
                longest_orf_start = len(sequence) - i - seq_rev.index(orf) - len(orf) +1
                longest_orf_end = len(sequence) - i - seq_rev.index(orf)
    print("Longest ORF:", longest_orf)
    print("Strand:", strand)
    print("Start position:", longest_orf_start)
    print("End position:", longest_orf_end)
    # Reverse complement the original DNA sequence
    seq_rev_comp = str(Seq(sequence).reverse_complement())
    # Translate the longest ORF to a protein sequence
    protein_seq = Seq(longest_orf).translate()
    print("Protein sequence:", protein_seq)
    protein_seq = str(protein_seq)

    return(longest_orf, protein_seq)
```

Comment: did you try to see if  `for i in range(1)` in your first loops gives different result respect to your `for i in range(3)` ??

Answer (score 1):

### The issue with this code is the `regular expression`:

```
(?s)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)
```

You can take a look at [**this**](https://regex101.com/) website to try out the `regex` with your `sequence`. The regular expression does not allow for overlaps. So what ends up happening is that it finds a hit, consumes the characters and ends up segmenting the **correct** `open reading frame`. You can see what I am talking about with the following image:

[image: erroneous regex]

Notice that the `second match` eats into the correct `orf` and the next `orf` that it finds is the **wrong answer**.

### To fix this we can use `(?=)` for `positive lookahead`:

```
(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?:TAG|TGA|TAA))
```

The `regex` is close to the original, except for the removal of `(?s)` and the addition of `(?=)`. So now that we allow for overlaps, we can get the answer we're looking for. Both instances of the `orfs` variable should now look like this:

```
orfs = re.findall(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?:TAG|TGA|TAA))', input_seq[i:])
```

Having made that change, gives me the following output:

```
Longest ORF: ATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAACGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCGCACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAACAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGGCTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTGA
Strand: +
Start position: 575
End position: 901
Protein sequence: MTTIRDSFNGSYQPNFDHWTADRHGDLCRTWTRCWRFSIGSAPLTSITNKSEVAKPDRTIKIPGVSPWKRSPVPTLPLTGYLSAFLPSGFLNAHAVGISVRCRSFAPS*
('ATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAACGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCGCACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAACAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGGCTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTGA', 'MTTIRDSFNGSYQPNFDHWTADRHGDLCRTWTRCWRFSIGSAPLTSITNKSEVAKPDRTIKIPGVSPWKRSPVPTLPLTGYLSAFLPSGFLNAHAVGISVRCRSFAPS*')
```

Answer (score 0):

my code is similar to yours, but uses Python Max() built-in function;

it is copied from [bioinformatics.stackexchange.com : Find open reading frames in a DNA sequence](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20442/find-open-reading-frames-in-a-dna-sequence/20452#20452)

```
import re

from Bio.Seq import Seq

sequence = ('GCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAAAATCGACGCGGTGGCGAAA'
       'CCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCTCCCTCG'
       'TGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGAAGCGTGGC'
       'TGCTCACGCTGTACCTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTGGGCTGTGTG'
       'CCGTTCAGCCCGACCGCTGCGCCTTATCCGGTAACTATCGTCTTGAGTCCAACCCGGTAA'
       'AGTAGGACAGGTGCCGGCAGCGCTCTGGGTCATTTTCGGCGAGGACCGCTTTCGCTGGAG'
       'ATCGGCCTGTCGCTTGCGGTATTCGGAATCTTGCACGCCCTCGCTCAAGCCTTCGTCACT'
       'CCAAACGTTTCGGCGAGAAGCAGGCCATTATCGCCGGCATGGCGGCCGACGCGCTGGGCT'
       'GGCGTTCGCGACGCGAGGCTGGATGGCCTTCCCCATTATGATTCTTCTCGCTTCCGGCGG'
       'CCCGCGTTGCAGGCCATGCTGTCCAGGCAGGTAGATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAA'
       'CGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCG'
       'CACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAA'
       'CAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAA'
       'GCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGG'
       'CTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGCTG'
       'ACGAACCCCCCGTTCAGCCCGACCGCTGCGCCTTATCCGGTAACTATCGTCTTGAGTCCA'
       'ACACGACTTAACGGGTTGGCATGGATTGTAGGCGCCGCCCTATACCTTGTCTGCCTCCCC'
       'GCGGTGCATGGAGCCGGGCCACCTCGACCTGAATGGAAGCCGGCGGCACCTCGCTAACGG'
       'CCAAGAATTGGAGCCAATCAATTCTTGCGGAGAACTGTGAATGCGCAAACCAACCCTTGG'
       'CCATCGCGTCCGCCATCTCCAGCAGCCGCACGCGGCGCATCTCGGGCAGCGTTGGGTCCT')

print(sequence,'\n\n')


def find_orfs(sequence):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))')
    
    
    revcompseq = sequence[::-1].maketrans("ATGC", "TACG") #reverse complement
    
    # print (pattern.findall(sequence)) #forward search
    # print (pattern.findall(sequence[::-1].translate(revcompseq))) #backward search
    
    
    b = [(m.span(1), m.start(1), m.end(1), (m.end(1)-m.start(1)), m, m.groups()[0] , 'forward') for m in re.finditer(pattern, sequence)]
    
    b_rev = [(m.span(1), m.start(1), m.end(1), (m.end(1)-m.start(1)), m, m.groups()[0] , 'reverse') for m in re.finditer(pattern, sequence[::-1].translate(revcompseq))]
    
    b = max(b, key= lambda x: x[3])
    
    try: 
        b_rev = max(b_rev, key= lambda x: x[3])
        
    except:
        
        b_rev = (0,0,0,0,0,0)
    
    
    b_max = max((b,b_rev), key= lambda x: x[3])
        
    
    # print(b,'\n', b_rev,'\n')
    
    
    
    print(b_max, type(b), b[4], len(b[5]))
    
    protein_seq = Seq(b_max[5]).translate()
    print("Protein sequence:", protein_seq)
    protein_seq = str(protein_seq)
    
    return(b_max[5], protein_seq)



print('\n\n',find_orfs(sequence))
```

output:

```
((573, 897), 573, 897, 324, <re.Match object; span=(573, 573), match=''>, 'ATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAACGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCGCACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAACAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGGCTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGC', 'forward') <class 'tuple'> <re.Match object; span=(573, 573), match=''> 324
Protein sequence: MTTIRDSFNGSYQPNFDHWTADRHGDLCRTWTRCWRFSIGSAPLTSITNKSEVAKPDRTIKIPGVSPWKRSPVPTLPLTGYLSAFLPSGFLNAHAVGISVRCRSFAPS


 ('ATGACGACCATCAGGGACAGCTTCAACGGCTCTTACCAGCCTAACTTCGATCACTGGACCGCTGATCGTCACGGCGATTTATGCCGCACATGGACGCGTTGCTGGCGTTTTTCCATAGGCTCCGCCCCCCTGACGAGCATCACAAACAAGTCAGAGGTGGCGAAACCCGACAGGACTATAAAGATACCAGGCGTTTCCCCCTGGAAGCGCTCTCCTGTTCCGACCCTGCCGCTTACCGGATACCTGTCCGCCTTTCTCCCTTCGGGCTTTCTCAATGCTCACGCTGTAGGTATCTCAGTTCGGTGTAGGTCGTTCGCTCCAAGC', 'MTTIRDSFNGSYQPNFDHWTADRHGDLCRTWTRCWRFSIGSAPLTSITNKSEVAKPDRTIKIPGVSPWKRSPVPTLPLTGYLSAFLPSGFLNAHAVGISVRCRSFAPS')
```

I an not sure if using `re.Match object` attributes it would be faster than your algorithm for big sequences, my code has a glitch: it assumes that there is only one ORF of the biggest lenght, as your algo too I believe.

if used with:

```
sequence = ('ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATGTAG'
            'ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG')
```

it returns the first of the 2 same lenght ORF of the sequence